# How to access Camel's property CamelLoopIndex from groovy element?

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

I have a setting of the headers with `groovy` elements like that:

```
  <setHeader headerName="time_to">
    <groovy>1625761488 - 3600*(properties.resolve(CamelLoopIndex)-1)</groovy>
  </setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="time_from">
    <groovy>1625761488 - 3600*properties.resolve(CamelLoopIndex)</groovy>
  </setHeader>
```

but when executing the route I'm getting the runtime error like that:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CamelLoopIndex for class: script16306769092271458244993
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
    at script16306769092271458244993.run(script16306769092271458244993.groovy:1)
```

So, the question is how to access the `CamelLoopIndex` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach here is to use `exchange.getProperty('CamelLoopIndex')`:

```
    <setHeader headerName="time_to">
        <groovy>1625761488 - 3600*(exchange.getProperty('CamelLoopIndex')-1)</groovy>
      </setHeader>
      <setHeader headerName="time_from">
        <groovy>1625761488 - 3600*exchange.getProperty('CamelLoopIndex')</groovy>
      </setHeader>
```